# Using CPP library in swift project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, bridging-header

I am trying to use a CPP library. in an iOS project. My experience with CPP is very brief and I am not sure how to perform the integration on iOS. I tried two options.

There is a static version of the Library composed from .a and .h files. The static version of the library is built for linux. Will this version work on iOS?
I tried to import the static library in Xcode, then I created a bridge file and tried to import the .h file there. I got an error telling me that .h file was not found.

In the second option I tried to import the source code of the library in my project. Xcode generated automatically the bridging header file. When I tried to run the code I got an error telling me that `#include "fftw3.h"` could not be found. `fftw3` seems to be a library used by the library I am trying to integrate. I found a pre-compiled version of the library for iOS `libfftw3f.a`. I tried to import in in Xcode but the problem remains.

Do you have an idea how should I proceeds? Would the static linux version of the library work on iOS or shall I use the source code? Do you have an idea or tips about the problem I am facing?

Answer (score 0):

At first you should make sure that you have linked all the dependencies that your library needs. Next, you need to create an ObjectiveC++ class (with the **.mm** extension) and make public methods which basically will forward the call to the c++ lib. Because you can't directly use C++ classes.. only ObjC classes through the bridging header.

Example:

Imagine you want to use some c++ class with name Foo which has a method named `void bar();`

So you need to make `FooWrapper` class with `FooWrapper.h` and `FooWrapper.mm` files, include the c++ header file in the `FooWrapper.mm` file, and make an objective-c method visible from swift code:

> FooWrapper.h

```
@interface FooWrapper: NSObject
- (void)bar;
@end
```

> FooWrapper.mm

```
#import "FooWrapper.h"
#include "..path/to/Foo.h"

@interface FooWrapper()
@property (nonatomic, assign) Foo *foo;
@end

@implementation FooWrapper
//...

- (void)bar
{
    foo->bar(); //forward call to the cpp lib
}
@end
```

Import `FooWrapper.h` to the bridging-header file (as you normally do with regular ObjC classes which you want to use in swift code), and use FooWrapper in your swift code:

> MySwiftClass.swift

```
class MySwiftClass {
    func bar() {
        let foo = FooWrapper()
        foo.bar()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure, with library you mean the static one or using the source code?

Comment: Its matter of your choice